# Where is it decided that the base URL should be redirected to Main_Page?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

The question title may speak for himself.

I would like to redirect my clients to something else than `www.my-wiki-address.org/index.php/Main_Page` when they enter the website url in there browser bar, that is `www.my-wiki-address.org`. 
I have dived into the code but cannot find out where the redirect is made.

I am using MediaWiki 1.19.1.

Comment: Do you want to change the name of the Main Page, or do something completely different?

Comment: And have a look at [*How do I change which page is the main page?*](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FAQ#How_do_I_change_which_page_is_the_main_page.3F)

Comment: I want to do something completely different. 
I want to redirect to a dynamically created page, populated with the content of the Wiki. Something similar to the main page of Wikipedia or even StackOverflow. 
I am having a look to your link. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But... you would have understood this is not really what I am looking for. I would like to dynamically populate the main page the way I want through PHP. For that I would need to know where the redirect toward `Main Page` takes place, which I for some reason do not manage to find out. I guess I could use `wfRunHooks( 'SetupAfterCache' );` is there is no other way.

Comment: I think the code that does that is in Wiki.php (search for `Title::newMainPage()`), but I'm not sure that's going to help you.

Comment: Thanks. But this is actually not called when I enter the base URL of my wiki. If I check the `$_SERVER['REQUESTED_URI']` variable, I see 'Main_Page' is already set as the page title at the very beginning of the request process. As if the redirect was caused by an `.htaccess` file but I cannot find any. 
So... I am stuck :)

Comment: Why do you need to know how the redirect is done? Just set the main page name to Special:MyMainPage and write a special page extension which shows whatever.

Comment: That is actually what I ended up doing. Thanks for poiting it out. One question however: Is it possible to do something else than setting a - ugly - redirect of the default `Main_Page` towards my `Special:Main_Page`? When you say: _Just set the main page name to Special:MyMainPage_, are you speaking about setting a redirect, or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

The title of the main page is defined by the interface message [MediaWiki:Mainpage](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aInterface/Mainpage), cf. e.g. [wiktionary:MediaWiki:Mainpage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/MediaWiki%3aMainpage). You can either set your MediaWiki:Mainpage to some special page implemented by yourself, or you can keep the “classic” Main Page location, but edit the page to include some dynamically generated contents using [custom tags](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTag_extensions) or [other extension points](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aExtensions) (again, possibly implemented by yourself), see e.g. the [RSS extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aRSS).